# Pandas Python: How to create lapse since today column?

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, how do I create a column that is the number of days a column 'Date' has lapsed since today? 
Since there are duplicate 'File's in my data, i need the max date only.

Here is my hypothetical data:

```
File,Status,Date
pafpull.sps,1,10-15-13 16:33 
pafpull.sps,1,10-14-13 16:33  
test.sps,1,10-14-13 11:19
```

Current Code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['File','Status','Date'])
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
xx=df.groupby('File')['Date'].max().order()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elapsed time should expressed as a `timedelta` type, which is what you get when you perform subtraction on two datetimes.

```
In [43]: datetime.now() - df['Date']
Out[43]:
0   38 days, 00:08:44.917269
1   39 days, 00:08:44.917269
2   39 days, 05:22:44.917269
```

To round it to the day, we have to jump through some hoops.

```
In [42]: datetime.now().date() - pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).normalize().to_series()
Out[42]:
2013-10-15   38 days, 00:00:00
2013-10-14   39 days, 00:00:00
2013-10-14   39 days, 00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

The reason for the mess is...a long story. Pandas support for timedeltas improves somewhat with the soon-to-be-released v0.13, but it has a ways to go.

Comment: assume numpy 1.7; iirc you can divide by np.timedelta64(1,'D') even in 0.12 (in 0.13 you can do an astype), see here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas-conversions

Answer (score 0):

went with a different solution since my final goal was to do logic on the lapse.

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
xx=df.groupby('File')['Date'].max().order()
df=pd.DataFrame(xx).reset_index()
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: (datetime.now() - x['Date']).days, axis=1)
```